# Chrome browser errors when running testcafe tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I run tests with TestCafe Studio, I will often times get a browser disconnected error, even though the browser is not closed, and seems to be running. Has anyone seen a fix for this.
I am running in a Linux AWS environment, using chrome.

[image]

Comment: This error can be caused by different reasons. Could you please clarify these points: 1) Does the error occur only with Chrome or with other browsers (e.g. Chrome headless, Firefox, remote browsers) too? 2) Does it occur during recording or when you run tests (or maybe in both cases)? 3) Is it related to some particular test and webpage to which the browser navigates? 4) Have you tried to run tests via TestCafe CLI?

Comment: It occurs when recording and playing tests.  However I don't recall ever seeing it using the command line. I've only used Chrome.  It does occur in headless mode as well.  It happens to other websites as well.